# When will the blockchain be pruned?

Tags: blockchain

AT what stage will the blockchain be pruned? With more update of bitcoins the blockchain will start growing exponentially making downloading thereof impractical.

Answer (score 1):

This is on the to-do list for the developers.  One proposal is to remove transactions that have been completely spent if they are fairly deep in the block chain (that is, there is minimal chance that a block chain reorganization could occur which would affect the transaction)